# Is it possible to forbid user running docker container to override the image's entrypoint?

Tags: security, docker

I find it a security issue that the user is able to override the **entrypoint** so can invoke `/bin/bash` and have root access.

Is it possible to forbid this in the dockerfile or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If user has the privilege to run Docker than he has root access to all containers anyway. This is not a security flaw at all. And the answer to your question is: no. You can always override the entrypoint when running a container.